# Where can I find DoS attack simulator

Tags: security, denial-of-service

I am taking a Security module and my project team intend to study DoS attacks by simulating them to better understand the mechanism, the damage and preventing mechanism, etc...

1. Could someone please give me an advice on where I can find a good DoS simulator?
2. Are there any simulators that can simulate a big range of DoS attack?
3. Can I carry out DoS in reality with just 1 computer without any zombie agents?

I am a newbie at this DoS topic. Please forgive me if my questions sound dumb to you :P.

Comment: Go piss off anonymous or some other group like that via a dummy system that uses your module :)

Comment: Security tools are off-topic here, but on-topic on [security.se]. However your question as it stands is not answerable. What kind of system are you studying (a router? a web server? an ATM?)? What kind of attackers are you looking at (over the Internet? with physical presence? targetted or not?)? I suggest that you post a new question (on [security.se]) that address these points.

Answer (score 1):

You may use following tools:

slowloris.pl, [PyLoris](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyloris/), [LOIC](https://github.com/NewEraCracker/LOIC/)

The LOIC is used by anonymous in your attacks.
Slowloris is specific for abuse of keep alive resource on Apache.